# How to add Column Heading list to multiple files with for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a for loop to name columns in multiple files. All of the files are .csv. After I name the files I want to append them. I think that I have a start on it below.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


df0 = pd.read_csv('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s110_s_b') 
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s111_s_b') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s112_s_b') 
df3 = pd.read_csv('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s113_s_b') 
file_list = ['df0', 'df1', 'df2', 'df3']

for file in file_list:

    file.columns = ['date', 'bill_id', 'sponsor_id']

    df0 = df0.append(df1)
    df0 = df0.append(df2)
    df0 = df0.append(df3)


print (df0)
```

but I get the following error:

```
`enter code here`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-5d50a0488b24> in <module>()
      9 file_list = ['df0', 'df1', 'df2', 'df3']
     10 for file in file_list:
---> 11     file.columns = ['date', 'bill_id', 'sponsor_id']
     12 df0.columns = ['date', 'bill_id', 'sponsor_id']
     13 df0 = df0.append(df1)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=['date','bill_id','sponsor_id']) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s11?_s_b')))
```

PS if your CSV files are relatively small then you may want to read them into one string and then create data frame out of that string.

Comment: How would I manage that if the files are not already named? Is there a way to index the columns? I'm looking now!

Comment: Do your CSV files have headers?

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you sir!

Comment: i've just updated an argument for `glob.glob()` - you may want to test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105613/discussion-between-michael-perdue-and-maxu).